# Conditional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

**This is my code**

```
foreach($orders as $order) {
array_push($list, array($order['name'],$order['email'],$order['financial_status']));
}
```

Now i got the value of financial_status is 1, I want to get value as true. I want  to add condition before the foreach loop.

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!.

Comment: Why do you want to add a condition? What condition? isn't `(bool)$order['financial_status']` what you want?

Comment: @Jon: I got the value of $order['financial_status'] is 1, I want to display as true not 1, Did you get my question? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need this maybe:

```
foreach($orders as $order) {
if ($order['financial_status'] == 1){
 $financial_status = true;
} else {
 $financial_status = false;
}
array_push($list, array($order['name'],$order['email'],$financial_status));
}
```

It will put boolean in array.

Comment: It will always be, as PHP puts it as 1-true/0-false, it you need it to be exact - "true"/"false" put like this:

    if ($order['financial_status'] == 1){
    $financial_status = "true";
    } else {
    $financial_status = "false";
    }

But in that case it will be put as a string and you'll need to cast later.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($orders as $order) {
if ($order['financial_status'] == 1){
return true
} else {
return false
}
array_push($list, array($order['name'],$order['email'],$financial_status));
}
```

check this edit
make sure to comparing with financial_status in table
if you want financial_status to return true when its value is 1 in sql and if true value required to be a different value change ==1 to that value

Comment: I tried your code, but it will display undefined variable "value". Thank you.